# number after $1 in urlrewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to put some numbers into a resulting url in urlrewrite rule, so from url like
"/test/723/"  I'll get "/test/700-series/723/"
Obviously this

```
RewriteRule ^/test/([1-9])([0-9]{2})/$  /test/$100-series/$1$2/
```

doesn't work because of $100 can't be interpreted correctly. Is there any way to separate $1 from any numbers behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close, just remove the leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([1-9])([0-9]{2})/?$  /test/$100-series/$1$2/ [L]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

As per [official Apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) It clearly states that:

> **RewriteRule backreferences**: These are backreferences of the form $N (0 <= N <= 9). $1 to $9 provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of RewriteCond conditions. $0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.

`Hence $100 is always interpreted as $1 and 2 literal zeroes.`

Comment: May I know why downvote here. (I had tested it before posting the answer)

Comment: the question is how to make Rewrite_Mod evaluate only $1, not $100.

Comment: And if you test my posted answer you will notice that it is rewriting `/test/723/` to `/test/700-series/723/` as needed by the OP.

Comment: And if you care to read the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html It clearly states that **`RewriteRule backreferences: These are backreferences of the form $N (0 <= N <= 9). $1 to $9 provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of RewriteCond conditions. $0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.`** Hence `$100` is always interpreted as `$1` and 2 literal zeroes.

Comment: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ , try and see, I think $10 is interpreted not only $1,  weird !

Comment: I have repeated this several times in my answers on SO to never test on that site as that is very unreliable. Always test on your web server to get the correct result. I would never have posted this answer without verifying it myself first.

Comment: you're right, please quote the doc in your answer to clear the issue. (you have to edit your answer so I can undo my downvote)

Comment: Leading slash was my typo in this post (not in config), thanks! And to tell the truth, I don't understand why my first try was wrong. Later I tried to test the rule via http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and there was no good (simulator doesn't track correctly this rule. Thank you for correct answer!